# How to provide different log levels to the loggers in the mix application?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I installed `rollbax` package, it provides ability to log output to [rollbar](http://rollbar.com) via their `Rollbax.Logger` module. The problem is that I want to have `level: :info` for the default elixir `:console` logger and `level: :error` for `Rollbax.Logger`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Rollbax.Logger.configure level: :error`?

Comment: How can I set `:console` logger level in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in config.exs, like this.

```
config :logger,
  backends:
    [
      :console,
      {Rollbax.Logger, :rollbax}
    ]

config :logger, :console,
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line],
  metadata_filter: [],
  compile_time_purge_level: :info,
  level: :info

config :logger, :rollbax,
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line],
  metadata_filter: [],
  compile_time_purge_level: :error,
  level: :error
```

Answer (score 0):

In `config/config.exs`:

```
config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n", level: :info
```

Somewhere in application:

```
Rollbax.Logger.configure level: :error
```